# Get signature of method from method decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript-decorator

I have a method decorator like this:

```
export function NumberMethodDecorator(message: string) {
  return (target: object, propertyKey: string, descriptor?: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) => {
    // do some stuff here
  }
}
```

I want to apply it like so:

```
class SomeClass {

  @NumberMethodDecorator("do some cool stuff")
  public someMethod(value: number) {

  }

}
```

However, I want to ensure that `NumberMethodDecorator` is only applied to methods with the signature `(value: number) => any`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify that in the type argument of `TypedPropertyDescriptor`:

```
export function NumberMethodDecorator(message: string) {
  return (
    target: object, propertyKey: string,
    descriptor?: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(value: number) => any>
  ) => {
    // do some stuff here
  };
}
```

Then when using:

```
class SomeClass {
  @NumberMethodDecorator("") // ok
  someMethod(value: number) {

  }

  @NumberMethodDecorator("") // compile error
  otherMethod() {
  }
}
```